# Gun Scene in Goldeneye

Tags: james-bond, continuity, goldeneye

In the James Bond film *Goldeneye* there is a scene were Bond threatens Valentin Dmitrovich Zukovsky. Zukovsky says something along the lines of:

> Walther PPK, 7.65mm. Only three men I know use such a gun... I believe I've killed two of them.

However, immediately afterward a henchman appears behind Bond with what appears (to me at least) to be an identical gun.  This leaves several options for me:

- Zukovsky was lying
- The guns are indeed different
- It's a continuity error

Which is correct?

Comment: Option 4: The Henchman took the weapon after his boss killed #1 or #2.

Comment: so the henchman doesn't know how to handle that gun? :D (because then there would be 4 people who know how to ... )

Comment: A screen shot would really add to this question..

Comment: @oers The question doesn't mention that people know 'how to handle' the gun, just that they use it.

Comment: @AidanO I agree, however I'm afraid I don't have the film on DVD only VHS

Comment: @AlasdairCM I would argue that the person pointing it at Bond's head is using it!

Comment: @Liath Yes, I agree, but oers has suggested about people knowing how to handle the gun

Comment: It's easy to overanalyze the meaning of "use". Certainly the villain implies with that word that only three people in the world carry and use that gun exclusively and habitually. For example, I think only the most pedantic and foolish villain would say "only three men I know use such a gun… well, four if you include my henchman Jenssen who recently acquired the recently departed Mr. Smith's gun… he's standing behind you right now."

Comment: The funny thing is that it is not a terribly uncommon gun. Not a favorite of a lot of ``gun guys'' but sold in considerable numbers none-the-less.

Comment: Watching the film recently, I watched out for this scene especially and it seemed that the villian was using a black pistol but I don't think it wasn't a Walter PPK. Has Goldeneye been released in HD? If it has, a HD screenshot should clearly should whether it's a PPK or not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When James Bond points his gun at Valentin Zukovsky it is clear that his gun is a Walter PPK. Notice there are no grooves on the side of the gun towards the back

[image: James Bond Walter PPK]

When Valentin's henchman points his gun at James, grooves can be seen on the side of the gun towards the back of the gun.
[image: Valentin's Henchman Gun]

This to me shows that the henchman is using a different gun and not a Walter PPK.

It would be a very bad mistake for the production team to have the henchman using a Walter PPK just after Valentin saying pretty much that there is only one person alive who uses it.

Comment: Anyone notice that the curtain is closed too in the second pic?

Comment: I think it's the henchman's leaning against the curtain that makes it look closed.

Answer (score 7):

The henchman's gun is a copy of the PPK that was produced in Soviet Russian known as the Makarov.  It is also a larger caliber, a 9x18mm.  I do believe that design is still being used by the Russian military to this day, as well as being a rather popular civilian gun. Thousands of them have been imported to the US.